# Update Xamarin.Android Contacts with ContentProvider

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, contacts

I am developing an app in Xamarin.Forms that lets the user save a contact and if the contact already exists it gets updated. The Xamarin.iOS side is already working.

So far, saving the contact works perfectly. For updating the contact I delete all of the phonenumbers and add them one by one again. Deleting all of the phonenumbers works already, I just can't add them again.

I've already tried using the RawContactID instead of just the ContactID and using the ContentProvider's "NewUpdate" function instead of "NewInsert". The result is always the same, I get no exceptions and the code runs smoothly. It just doesn't add anything.

Here is the part of my code that returns the contact id, which I want to update:

```
 public string GetPhoneContactID(Contact contact)
        {
            string id = "0";
            var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;
            var cursor = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, new string[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id },
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName +
                 "='" + GetDisplayName(contact.FirstName, contact.LastName) + "'", null, null);
            if (cursor.MoveToNext())
            {
                id = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id));
            }
            cursor.Close();
            return id;
        }
```

The code that updates the contact:

```
public bool UpdateExistingContact(Contact contact)
        {
            var id = GetPhoneContactID(contact);

            string selection = ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype + "=?";
            String[] selectionArgs = new string[] { id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentItemType };

// DELETE ALL PHONE NUMBERS FROM CONTACT
            Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Delete(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
List<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new List<ContentProviderOperation>();

                var counterPhoneNumbers = 0;
                if (contact.PhoneNumbers != null)
                {
// ADD NEW PHONENUMBERS TO CONTACT
                    while (counterPhoneNumbers < contact.PhoneNumbers.Count)
                    {
                        var builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
                        builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, id);
                        builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype,
                                          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentItemType);
                        builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number, contact.PhoneNumbers[counterPhoneNumbers].Value);                            builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Data2, (int)PhoneDataKind.Work);
                        ops.Add(builder.Build());

                        counterPhoneNumbers++;
                    }
                }
                ContentProviderResult[] result;
                try
                {
                    result = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.ApplyBatch(ContactsContract.Authority, ops);
                    if (result.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ops.Clear();
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error(ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to stem from the Android simulator on Visual Studio - running it on a physical device works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wantt to update a contact's information. You can just use the

```
 public void ChangeContactNumber(Context context, string oldnumber,string newnumber)
        {
            if (context == null) return ;
            var cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri,
                    new string[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number },
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number + "=?",
                    new string[] { oldnumber },
                    null
            );
            if (cursor == null || cursor.Count == 0) return;
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            string id = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id));
            //get the contactid here
            var contentvalues = new ContentValues();
            var where = ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id + "=?" + " AND "  + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number + "=?";
            var whereArgs = new String[] { id, oldnumber };
            contentvalues.Put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number, newnumber);
            Uri uri = Uri.Parse("content://com.android.contacts/data");
            context.ContentResolver.Update(uri, contentvalues, where, whereArgs);
        }
```

In addition, when you get the contactid, you can change the name, email and other info by the `ContentResolver.Update`